# How to subtract the value from the previous value in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to take values in a list, such as `[1,2,3]` and subtract them from each other. So it would return `[-1,-1]` because the first value is `1-2` and the second value is `2-3`. How would i achieve this in python? I have tried

```
[x-y for (x,y) in list]
```

but this gives a 'need more than one value to unpack error.'

Comment: If your list is called `list` then you have more than one problem. But try using `range` to access elements by position instead of directly looping over the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a good idea to shadow the builtin `list`, so I changed your variable name here

```
[x - y for x, y in zip(the_list, the_list[1:])]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to use `numpy.diff`, this is quite easy:

```
In [22]: import numpy as np

In [23]: -np.diff([1,2,3])
Out[23]: array([-1, -1])

In [24]: -np.diff([1,2,4,3])
Out[24]: array([-1, -2,  1])
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer; may also add the note that a list X may be converted to a numpy array via X = np.array(X) or alternatively diffs = np.diff(np.array(X))

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a generator created by izipping the list with itself, offset by one index.

```
from itertools import izip, islice
[x - y for x,y in izip(lst, islice(lst, 1, None))]
```

This is handy if for some reason `lst` was itself a generator, or otherwise was not easily examined for its length ahead of time, or you just didn't want to consume it directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension, but specify a `range` starting at 1 to the end of the list (or alternatively starting at zero to one minus the length of the list):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [lst[i - 1] - lst[i] for i in range(1, len(lst))]
[-1, -1]
```

Comment: I got typeerror unsupport types for -: int and list?

Comment: Works fine for me using Python 2.7.10.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @Jared: that error suggests you might have a typo and you might be trying to "subtract" the list and the index offset.