# How can I create a process loop in a series?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, for-loop, series

In the series below, I want to create a new series by subtracting the previous value from the next value.

```
y = [50, 62, 89, 75, 72]
Progress  = [[62-50], [89-62], [75-89], [72-75]]    
Result = [12, 27, -14, -3]
```

I tried to write code like this;

```
y = [50, 62,  89, 75, 72]
for i in y:
    print(i + 1 - i)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to subtract the value from the previous value in a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556700/how-to-subtract-the-value-from-the-previous-value-in-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip to jointly iterate over 2 iterablea, slicing and a list comprehension like

```py
result =[p-c for p, c in zip(nums[1:], nums[:-1])]
```

Or just via indexing like

```py
result = [nums[i] - nums[i-1] for i in range(1, len(nums))]
```

Comment: You forget a bracket in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `numpy` tag, the easiest way is to use `diff`:

```
new = np.diff(y)
```

Output:

```
array([ 12,  27, -14,  -3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
nums = iter([50, 62, 89, 75, 72])
prev = next(nums, None)
result = []
for num in nums:
    result.append(num - prev)
    prev = num
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `numpy` as suggested by @fsl.

However, if you want a pure python solution and have python ≥ 3.10 you can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```
from itertools import pairwise

result = list(map(lambda x: x[1]-x[0], pairwise(y)))
```

for python < 3.10, you can define pairwise:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    # pairwise('ABCDEFG') --> AB BC CD DE EF FG
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```